# hyperlink not working in a pdf in a UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have text file (instructions.docx) with a hyperlink in it - I convert it to a pdf (instructions.pdf) and use it in a UIWebView as follows:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Instructions" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
[_webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
```

All works fine except the hyperlink does not work - shows blue - but tapping it does nothing.
Am I going about this the wrong way - or am I missing something?

Comment: I have similar problem, though it opens on the second tap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but you can try this line of code:

```
[_webView setDataDetectorTypes:UIDataDetectorTypeLink];
```

Otherwise, you can try [Reader](https://github.com/vfr/Reader) library by vfr. PDF embedded links work in it.

Also you may want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4875902/1512977).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Turns out the links in the PDF weren't hyperlinks. They were just typed in (even though they were blue and looked like real hyperlinks).

Resolved the issue by:

1. Manually adding hyperlinks
2. Checked Word to PDF conversion allowed for "Best for electronic distribution and accessibility"